# How to just show few lines from a whole blog-post on a certain page?

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a blog in which I want to show just the summary of all posts on the home page rather than whole posts.
Below is the function that I use to get the posts on my home page.

```
function get_content($id = '')
{
    if ($id != ""):

        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
        $sql = "SELECT * from cms_content WHERE id = '$id'";
        $return = '<p><a href="http://localhost/www/">Go back to Home page</a></p>';
        echo $return;
    else:

        $sql = "select * from cms_content ORDER BY id DESC";
    endif;

    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) != 0):

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            echo '<h1><a href="index.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['title'] . '</a></h1>';
            echo '<p>' . "by: " . $row['author'] . ", posted on: " . $row['date'] . '<p>';
            echo '<p>' . $row['body'] . '</p><br />';
        }
    else:
        echo '<p>We are really very sorry, this page does not exist!</p>';
    endif;
}
```

And then simply I use this php code to get the posts:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['id'])) :
    $obj->get_content($_GET['id']);
else :
    $obj->get_content();
endif;
?>
```

So how to get the summary only using php function or mysql as I know that we can use mysql query to get limit the words?

Comment: Please use braces in your code instead of the colon syntax, it makes your code a whole lot more readable.

Comment: But my code is redeable at this moment, and this is not a issue right here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function sumarize($your_string, $limit_lines){
   $count = 0;
   foreach(explode("\n", $your_string) as $line){
       $count++;
       echo $line."\n";
       if ($count == $limit_lines) break;        
   }
} 
sumarize($row['body'], 10);
```

will show first ten lines

Comment: You mean to put the function sumarize() in function.php file as I have made and then put sumarize($row['body'], 10); in the php code which i use to show posts on page as i have shown in my second portion of code?

Comment: If it is so, I am getting the following error:- Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\index.php on line 38

Notice: Undefined variable: count in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\_classes\cms-class.php on line 40

Comment: @AmitYadav: yes, $row['body'] should be changed to variable which have body you wanna summarize inside

Comment: so it means that $row isn't there. You should change that to current text body variable

Comment: I am really close solving my problem. I am newbie in PHP, so i could not understand at all what must be current text body variable. If you can, please help me, I will provide all the necessary information to you.

Comment: @AmitYadav: change your while loop to `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                echo '<h1><a href="index.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['title'] . '</a></h1>';
                echo '<p>' . "by: " . $row['author'] . ", posted on: " . $row['date'] . '<p>';
                echo '<p>' . sumarize($row['body'],10) . '</p><br />';
            }`

Comment: Thanks!, it worked. But I had to make two changes. 1:- i have change the sumarize() code totaly as your was not taking care of html codes, and 2: -echo '<p>' . $this->sumarize($row['body'],10) . '</p><br />';

Comment: @AmitYadav: 1. Sure, it was just a function to show you how to continue 2. I couldn't know that you'll put it into class

Answer (score 1):

1-lined:

```
echo '<p>'.implode("\n",array_slice(explode("\n",$row['body']),0,10)).'</p>';
```

instead of line with `$row['body']`

Comment: But where i should put this line? and my $text_you_need_to_cut is in the database, so how to put this in a variable??

Comment: replace your variable by this. Try to learn basic of PHP before using it!

Comment: I really can not understand what to replace there with  $text_you_need_to_cut. My table name is cms_content and the row which holds the body of posts is named as"body". do i need to replace it with $body?